# ng-content transclude from parents scope when there are nested components

Tags: javascript, angular, transclusion

Using Angular 2/4, I have a complex page template.

Suppose I have 3 mutually nested components: `page.component`, inside that `header.component` and inside that `header.title.component` with custom selectors set appropriately.

`page.component` html template:

```
<layout-header></layout-header>
...
```

`header.component` html template:

```
<section class="dynamic-content" *ngIf="!collapsed" #dynamicContent>
  <layout-header-title></layout-header-title>
  ...
</section>
```

`header.title.component` html template:

```
<ng-content selector="card-layout-title"></ng-content>
```

Then, on my actual page template:

```
<layout-page>
  <card-layout-title>Title goes here</card-layout-title>
</layout-page>
```

The `ng-content selector="card-layout-title"` only works when the direct parent is the component with the tag inside to select, i.e. from `header.title.component` I am unable to select 2-levels-up the nested components to find the content to transclude into `card-layout-title`.

How can I do this (preferably without adding and passing a template ref into each level, as there are 5-10 nested components at each level)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's `<ng-content select=".card-layout-title"></ng-content>` and not `<ng-content selector=".card-layout-title"></ng-content>`; easy mistake to make, given the lack of documentation.

It seems, from my testing, that using Transclusion in Angular 2/4 replaces the top-level content first, so that by the time it gets down to the `ng-content` selector, the `.card-layout-title` element no longer exists. So, I propose that a solution to this problem be that you "walk" the top-level content down the chain with nested `ng-content` elements. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdOMgLxCHpgQjiQXHV5H?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for the plunkr and realizing my mistake with `selector=`,  I've forked your plunkr here to demonstrate an issue I've been having with this solution. The DOM copies "card-layout-title" multiple times (even if you use a class instead of a tag). Try inspecting the title you'll see what I mean http://plnkr.co/edit/gD1IMFFJAsz61gIRSfsb?p=preview . `ng-content` isn't shedding the tag like I think it should so there is *heaps* of DOM noise

Comment: I fixed this here using `ngProjectAs`. There's no documentation for this, so I just guessed and it seemed to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/UTSOtkx0IGq6vTsd3v3H?p=preview . I've edited your answer, I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 6):

I split this additional information out from the answer by @dohpaz42 as it's a lot less relevant to the general use-case.

If your heirarchy is **not** completely flat i.e.

```
<layout-dyn-page>
  <layout-header>
    <layout-title>Title</layout-title>
    <layout-summary>Summary</layout-summary>
  <layout-header>
</layout-dyn-page>
```

the solution above will not work as `ng-content select=` does not select elements that aren't in the top level. When you try and project them downwards, you project them with their wrapping tag no matter how you try, so currently selecting elements nested within by tag seems impossible. You must flatten it i.e.

```
<layout-dyn-page>
  <layout-title>Title</layout-title>
  <layout-summary>Summary</layout-summary>
</layout-dyn-page>
```

This could very well be a bug (or missing feature) in angular, but for now (without documentation) we can't know.